# cannot add onclick event to dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that is meant to dynamically create row items. My problem is the creation of the last cell item, a button. I have tried using onclick, setAttribute and attachEvent. But either the button is created or the onclick event is launched in the addGarageRow() function which creates the button and not the onclick event of the created button itself

```
  function addGarageRow(tableID)
   {
     var table=document.getElementById(tableID);

     rownum = rownum + 1;
     var rowCount=table.rows.length;
     var row=table.insertRow(rowCount);

     var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
     var element1=document.createElement("input");
     element1.type="checkbox";
     element1.name="chk[]";

     cell1.appendChild(element1);


     var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
     var element2=document.createElement("input");
     element2.type="text";
     element2.id=rownum;
     element2.name="garage_for[]";

     cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
    var element3=document.createElement("input");
    element3.type="text";
    element3.id="amount"+rownum;
    element3.name="garage_amount[]";
    cell3.appendChild(element3); 

    var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
    var element4=document.createElement("input");
    element4.setAttribute("type", "button");
    element4.id=rownum;
    //element4.name="voucher";
    //element4.onclick = alert("test");
    //element4.setAttribute("onClick", alert("test");
    //element4.attachEvent('OnClick',Hi());
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

 }
```

Comment: the `id` of an element must begin with a letter. maybe your `input`'s `id`'s are erroneous (as i see in `element4.id=rownum;`).

Comment: `onclick` need a reference to a function, like `function(){ alert("test") }`

Answer (score 3):

The handler should be wrapped in a function. i.e:

```
element4.onclick = function(){
   alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap the function you would like to be executed when the `onclick` event fires inside a `function` block. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/qbhfdkq3/